# eclipse can't be launched in administrative privileges

Tags: eclipse, fedora, privileges

I just want to use eclipse with root user.
In my fedora 26 system, eclipse pop out a dialog about "The Eclipse executable launcher is configured to not start with administrative privileges", after that, it exists.

How to configure it to go?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's all because of Eclipse runtime option:

```
-protect [root, master] (Executable, Main)
```

setting the value to "root" prevents Eclipse from being started as a root user, either directly or via programs that run with administrative privileges like 'sudo'. This option is currently implemented only on Linux/UNIX based platforms.

PS: "master" can be used to prevent starting of the master instance in a shared install configuration. This option can be used on all platforms supported by Eclipse.

Switch it off and Eclipse will start as normally.
To switch it off delete two first lines of code which contain this option from your eclipse.ini file.